# default image when there isnt any image in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, image

i want to show coming-soon.jpg image if there is not any image for that particular id. i have used join query to fetch data from two table. so there are many images in database for different different id. but if there isnt any image for particular id then its shoe coming-soon.jpg

below is my code.

```
 <table width="100%" border="0" id="batch">
<? 
include("includes/paging.php");
$p = new post_pager(16); 
$photo_detail="select a.*,b.* from office_photo a,office_master b where a.album_id=b.album_id group by a.album_id";  
$p->query($photo_detail, "b.album_id asc", init());
$thispage = "Photo";
if ($p->page_total > 0 ) {  
$int_count = $p->get_counter();
$i=1;
while($row= tep_db_fetch_array($p->recresult))
{
$file_id=$row["file_id"];
$file_name=$row["file_name"];
$album_name=$row["album_name"];
$sqft=$row["sqft"];
$location=$row["location"];
$year=$row["year"];
$album_id=$row["album_id"];
if($i==1){ ?>
<tr>
<th>Project Name</th>
<th>Sq.Ft.</th>
<th>Loctaion</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Gallery</th>
</tr>
<? } ?>
<tr>
<td><a title="<?=$album_name;?>" href="office-photos.php?album_id=<?=$album_id?>" style="text-decoration:none">
<p style="text-align:center;padding-top:5px;width:140px;text-decoration:none"><?=$album_name;?></p></a></td>
<td><?=$sqft;?></td>
<td><?=$location;?></td>
<td><?=$year;?></td>
<td><a title="<?=$album_name;?>" href="office-photos.php?album_id=<?=$album_id?>" style="text-decoration:none">
<img src="upload/gallery_photo/thumb/<?=$file_name;?>"/></a></td>
</tr>
<? 
if($i==4){ 
$i=1; 
?>
<? }else {
$i = $i + 1;
}
}
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(empty($file_name))
{$file_name="coming-soon.jpg";}//put any default image here
```

Answer (score 1):

in your while loop, replace code with this line.

```
$file_name=(!empty($row["file_name"])?$row["file_name"] : 'default-img.jpg');
```

Comment: i make change as below but not woking

Comment: do this `var_dump($row["file_name"])` and see what you are getting.

Comment: i have made changes as below but still its not working

' while($row= tep_db_fetch_array($p->recresult))
    {
    $file_id=$row["file_id"];
    $file_name=(!empty($row["file_name"])?$row["file_name"] : 'default-img.jpg');
    $album_name=$row["album_name"];'

Comment: do you have image named `default-img.jpg` in your folder `thumb`?

Comment: do this var_dump($row["file_name"]) and see what you are getting.

Comment: i did this its shows some thing ' string(17) "5399tnkvfnber.jpg" ' its some other gallery image

    $file_name=(!empty($row["file_name"])?var_dump($row["file_name"]) : 'coming-soon.jpg');

Comment: if it's showing `string(17) "5399tnkvfnber.jpg` it means image is in database , and if still not showing means, image is not in folder. you want to show default image when this case happens ? you have to use `file_exists` function

Answer (score 0):

```
if($file_name == '')
{
$file_name="defaultimg.jpg";//use your default image name here
}
```